# Save username and password in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have been working on creating a chatbot using Google Dialogflow. I was just wondering if anyone else has done this and incorporated usernames and passwords. For instance, I would like to have the user enter a username and then have this username persist throughout the chat so that I can save other data such as a password, address, etc to a Firebase realtime database. Has anyone else done something similar?

Thank you.